# When does an application show up on the taskbar?

Tags: forms, delphi

I have an application that shows a subform on startup. I've put the subform.showmodal on mainform.onCreate but the application does not show up on the taskbar until later. When is the application placed on the taskbar, and when is it  prudent to show subforms on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: I am assuming that you are using a modern Delphi and setting `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` to `True` early in your .dpr file. That is, the taskbar button is associated with the main form's window handle.

Simplifying a little, taskbar buttons are shown for unowned top-level windows that are visible.

So, the taskbar button for your main form is created when the main form becomes visible. That happens with a call to `ShowWindow` that is made from `TCustomForm.CMShowingChanged`. The framework makes this call to `ShowWindow` after the virtual `DoShow` is executed, and therefore after the form's `OnShow` event executes. So you will find that code in an `OnShow` handler happens before the taskbar button is created.

As I read your question, you wish to show your modal form as soon as possible after the main form is shown. Do that by handling `CM_SHOWINGCHANGED`:

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_SHOWINGCHANGED;
  end;

....

procedure TMainForm.CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if Visible and ModalSubFormHasNotBeenShown then
    ShowModalSubForm;
end;
```